# NETSNMP does not update the EngineTime after "SNMP Not In Time Window" error, how to manually reset the internal NETSNMP SSL structures?

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I use the NETSNMP library to request data from a router using SNMPv3 and authentication. If the router is reset the internal EngineTime is reset which is not recognized by the NETSNMP library. This causes the router to throw a authentication failure in subsequent calls.

Is there any api call to NETSNMP to manually reset the internal structures so a fresh request is made?

I enclose every call in snmp_sess_open/close so there is no open sessions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a hard-reset on the router you're going to be in trouble.  When a router reboots the SNMPv3 specifications **require** that the snmpEngineBoots counter increments, and the snmpEngineTime resets to 0.  If your device is rebooting without the snmpEngineBoots value incrementing (ie, it's always 0 or 1), then yes the running manager will see a problem because the device is reporting that it's going backward in time.

If you really want to ignore the security problems with doing this, you can always call:

```
int             set_enginetime(const u_char * engineID, u_int engineID_len,
                               u_int engine_boot, u_int engine_time,
                               u_int authenticated);
```

**but** you must understand that the instant you do that you're setting yourself up for replay attacks.  So **don't** let your device reset without the snmpEngineBoots value incrementing or, failing that, changing it's snmpEngineID.